# heroku db:pull strange response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i run

```
$ heroku db:pull
```

it says

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: mysql2://root:mypassword@127.0.0.1/app?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the database 'mysql2://root:mypassword@127.0.0.1/app?encoding=utf8' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: heroku-app-9999
 !    To proceed, type "heroku-app-9999" or re-run this command with --return heroku-app-9999
```

so i run

```
$ cryptic-harbor-6329
```

then i get this response:

```
!    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 !        <html>
 !        <head>
 !          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 !          <style type="text/css">
 !            html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }
 !            iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }
 !          </style>
 !        <title>Application Error</title></head>
 !        </head>
 !        <body>
 !          <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">
 !            <p>Application Error</p>
 !          </iframe>
 !        </body>
 !        </html>
```

i have pulled and pushed to heroku with different apps many times. i have never received this error. what dose it mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku db:pull mysql://root:mypass@localhost/mydb
```

try this